# Drive traffic now, winter is coming

Tags: discussion

I've been playing around with google trends.

Camping: http://www.google.com/trends/?q=camping&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0
Hiking: http://www.google.com/trends/?q=hiking&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0
Backpack: http://www.google.com/trends/?q=backpack&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0

Camping and hiking searches peak every summer (northern hemisphere).

Skiing: http://www.google.com/trends/?q=skiing&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0

Skiing peaks in the winter.

Comment: Give an example. Start asking now :)

Comment: @lechlukasz - I added some examples of what I was talking about

Comment: ...or we just search around for some southern hemisphere interest? ;)

Answer (score 7):

That's a great point about traffic peaking for certain outdoor activities at certain times. I wonder if we could borrow an idea from the SciFi.SE site. Over at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/ they do weekly themes and have prizes for top questions and such. Not saying we need to have prizes right away, but making a push for themed questions in the correct seasons could help spur seasonal traffic.

For example: 
Summer: Canoeing, Fishing 
Fall: Hiking, Backpacking 
Winter: Skiing, ice-fishing 
Spring: Bird-watching, Thru-hike

So then each of those would be a tag that users would add to their question during the week/month of the competition. Not really sure where we go from there because I don't know what is reasonable. A partnership with an outdoor company and some SWAG would be awesome.